# KnockoutJS "checked" binding doesn't work with observableArray and radio button lists

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have an observableArray called `SelectedAttributeValueIds` which I need to be bound to a radio button list using the "checked" binding. e.g.

```
<input type="radio" data-bind="checked: SelectedAttributeValueIds" />
```

However KnockoutJS is replacing the observableArray with a single value that is just observable. so instead of the SelectedAttributeValueIds having a value of [123] it will be "123"

I did this as a workaround but was wondering if there is an easier way:

```
<input type="radio" data-bind="event: { change: function() { $parent.SelectedAttributeValueIds([$data.ID()]); } }" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For radio buttons, KO assumes that there will only be one "value" to write.  For checkboxes, it would add/remove values from the array.

It sounds like you want to always write a single value, but have it be in an array as the only element.

One option would be to create a `ko.computed` to represent the item in an array.  Another option would be to use a writeable `ko.computed` to bind against the input and have it broker the value between the formats that you want.  Something like:

```
this.SelectedAttributeValueIds = ko.observableArray();
this.SelectedAttributeValueId = ko.computed({
   read: function() {
       var values = this.SelectedAttributeValueIds();
       return values.length ? values[0] : [];
   },
   write: function(newValue) {
       this.SelectedAttributeValueIds([newValue]);
   },
   owner: this
});
```

Comment: I tried this out but it passes "true" or "false" for newValue when I need it to be the value thats stored in the value="" attribute on the HTML element

Comment: Here is a fiddle that you can try to reproduce off of: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/LWeQ8/

Comment: Ok I'll give that a shot tomorrow at work. I was hopeing there was a different way of doing this other then this way.. but I guess not :(

Comment: This worked, Thanks although I had to change this:
read: function()
     {
      var values = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(this.SelectedAttributeValueIds);
      return values.length ? values[0] : null;
     },

Comment: Yep, the observableArray should have been unwrapped.